# MySQL Backup with WHERE Condition

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to backup a MySQL Table with a WHERE Condition?
For example,
I have a table with a date AND time column.

**Now I want to backup that table with date >= '2013-08-01'.**

What I have in mind is to SELECT the data I needed to a temporary table then backup that temporary table.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TRY this :

$db_user = "username";
$db_pass = "password";

exec("mysqldump --opt -u$db_user -p$db_pass --no-create-info --where date >= '2013-08-01' my_database my_table > backup.sql");
```

Comment: @user1051505 how so? there isn't a loop here, the infinite loop is probably in your own code

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to ***backup a MySQL Table with a WHERE Condition***

Try the below Query

```
select * --specify column name or back up every column
into back_up_table
from table_name
where date >= '2013-08-01'
```

Comment: I know how to select data with a where condition to a temporary table, then backup that temporary table.  
What I need to know is if there is another way, e.g. mysqldump with where condition.